# List names of aliases, functions and variables in zsh

Tags: shell, zsh

I need a way to list the names (without the body/content/value) of aliases, functions, variables, arrays in zsh. Optimally it should behave like `compgen`:

```
compgen -a # will list all the aliases you could run.
compgen -A function # will list all the functions you could run.
compgen -A variable # will list all the variables defined.
```

**Background**

I need this to develop env_parallel.zsh: https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/env_parallel.html

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Aliases and functions are contained in `aliases` and `functions`, and one merely needs to print the keys of such. "Variables and arrays" is trickier; `parameters` may suffice?

```
print -rl -- ${(k)aliases} ${(k)functions} ${(k)parameters}
```

(You may also need `builtins`, `commands`, and perhaps other things listed from `print -l ${(k)` and then mashing <kbd>tab</kbd>, assuming completion is enabled.)

Comment: Maybe `${(kM)parameters:#[[:alpha:]_][[:alnum:]_]#}` (with `extendedglob`) for _only_ the parameters that are variables.

Comment: `for k in ${(koM)parameters:#[[:alpha:]][[:alnum:]_]#}; do; [[ ${(M)parameters[$k]:#association*} ]] || continue; print -- "$k"; done` (`extendedglob` needs to be set) should give you a short list of variables to use depending on what data you are looking for.  Changing `[[:alpha:]]` to `[[:alpha:]_]` will include associative arrays(or variables) which start with an underscore. Changing `association*` to `scalar*` or `array*` or `integer*` or `*export*` will give you the results of those types. "Variables and arrays" take a bit more work.